# How can I set scale to BigDecimal in lambda expression

Tags: java

I have this code

```
return Optional.ofNullable(value)
               .map(String::valueOf)
               .map(BigDecimal::new)
               .orElse(null);
```

How Can I add `setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING)`  to this expression?

Comment: `.map(b -> b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING))` before ofElse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand the mapping

```
return Optional.ofNullable(value)
        .map(v -> new BigDecimal(v).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING))
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Should `v` be `value` (or vice versa)?

Comment: "v" is whatever you name the variables in that mapping step. You can freely choose

Comment: @GorillAndee "freely" with the exception of `value` (in this case), because that identifier is already used